# Calculating the sum of values of a given column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
rails 3.2

Invoice.sum(:amount)
```

Accurately returns the sum of all values in the amount column.

If I do the following:

```
invoices = Invoice.all
```

And then:

```
invoices.sum(:amount)
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `map` function, like this:

```
invoices.map(&:amount).sum
```

Comment: This is iterating twice over the same array, which is not optimal. It will work, but also does not address the initial question which is 'why' doesn't `invoices.sum(:amount)` work.  It's because the OP is mixing up activerecord and vanilla ruby.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @Gustavo Fe If I need sum two colums like  invoices.map(&:amount + &:fees ).sum is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you are certain that there is not a single `amount == nil` then what you tried, should work. If you have a single nil column this would result in 
`NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil`. In this case you can either do `invoices.map(&:amount).compact.sum` or `invoices.sum { |i| i.amount || 0 }`

Comment: I have no nil values and I still get the error message

Answer (score 3):

This is because #sum is an ActiveRecord method.  What it is essentially doing is building the aggregation into your database query like so (in SQL):

```
SELECT SUM(name_of_column_to_sum) FROM table_name;
```

If you want to return the values and store them in a variable (#all),

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

and THEN sum them, you are no longer working with an ActiveRecord query, but rather an ActiveRecord relation (an array-like object that is returned from the ActiveRecord query).  So, at that point you would need to use vanilla Ruby to sum up.  You could use #map and then #sum, but it would be faster and cleaner to just use #inject, like so:

```
invoices.inject(0){ |sum, invoice| sum + invoice.amount }
```

Comment: Used this to get rid of N+1 query's I was have. Thank you for posting this BTW. Was wondering if you know if this is a proper way to get rid of the N+1?  Looking at my logs it does do that but I'm unaware if it is the "proper way".

Comment: @Chrismisballs the "proper" way is often different depending on your use case, however, a good rule of thumb is this..  Avoid loading things into memory that you don't have to.  In this case, `.all` is building a whole bunch of activerecord objects in memory just to iterate over one value.  It's smarter to use the `.sum` activerecord method in this case than to use `.inject`.  [For more on that check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449617/why-is-sum-so-much-faster-than-inject)