# Why is sum so much faster than inject(:+)?

Tags: ruby

So I was running some benchmarks in Ruby 2.4.0 and realized that

```
(1...1000000000000000000000000000000).sum
```

calculates immediately whereas

```
(1...1000000000000000000000000000000).inject(:+)
```

takes so long that I just aborted the operation. I was under the impression that `Range#sum` was an alias for `Range#inject(:+)` but it seems like that is not true. So how does `sum` work, and why is it so much faster than `inject(:+)`?

**N.B.** The documentation for `Enumerable#sum` (which is implemented by `Range`) does not say anything about lazy evaluation or anything along those lines.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

## Short answer

For an integer range :

- `Enumerable#sum` returns `(range.max-range.min+1)*(range.max+range.min)/2`
- `Enumerable#inject(:+)` iterates over every element.

---

## Theory

The sum of integers between 1 and `n` is called a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and is equal to `n*(n+1)/2`.

The sum of integers between `n` and `m` is the triangular number of `m` minus the triangular number of `n-1`, which is equal to `m*(m+1)/2-n*(n-1)/2`, and can be written `(m-n+1)*(m+n)/2`.

## Enumerable#sum in Ruby 2.4

This property in used in [`Enumerable#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) for integer ranges :

```
if (RTEST(rb_range_values(obj, &beg, &end, &excl))) {
    if (!memo.block_given && !memo.float_value &&
            (FIXNUM_P(beg) || RB_TYPE_P(beg, T_BIGNUM)) &&
            (FIXNUM_P(end) || RB_TYPE_P(end, T_BIGNUM))) { 
        return int_range_sum(beg, end, excl, memo.v);
    } 
}
```

`int_range_sum` looks like this :

```
VALUE a;
a = rb_int_plus(rb_int_minus(end, beg), LONG2FIX(1));
a = rb_int_mul(a, rb_int_plus(end, beg));
a = rb_int_idiv(a, LONG2FIX(2));
return rb_int_plus(init, a);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(range.max-range.min+1)*(range.max+range.min)/2
```

the aforementioned equality!

## Complexity

Thanks a lot to @k_g and @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil for this part!

#### sum

`(1...1000000000000000000000000000000).sum`
requires three additions, a multiplication, a substraction and a division.

It's a constant number of operations, but multiplication is O((log n)²), so `Enumerable#sum` is O((log n)²) for an integer range.

#### inject

`(1...1000000000000000000000000000000).inject(:+)`

requires 999999999999999999999999999998 additions!

Addition is O(log n), so `Enumerable#inject` is O(n log n).

With `1E30` as input, `inject` with never return. The sun will explode long before!

## Test

It's easy to check if Ruby Integers are being added :

```
module AdditionInspector
  def +(b)
    puts "Calculating #{self}+#{b}"
    super
  end
end

class Integer
  prepend AdditionInspector
end

puts (1..5).sum
#=> 15

puts (1..5).inject(:+)
# Calculating 1+2
# Calculating 3+3
# Calculating 6+4
# Calculating 10+5
#=> 15
```

Indeed, from `enum.c` comments :

> `Enumerable#sum` method may not respect method redefinition of `"+"`
>   methods such as `Integer#+`.

Comment: This is a really good optimization to have since calculating the sum of a range of numbers is trivial if you use the right formula, and excruciating if you go about it iteratively. It's like trying to implement multiplication as a series of addition operations.

Comment: So the performance boost is for `n+1` ranges only? I don't have 2.4 installed or I would test myself but are other Enumerable Objects handled by basic addition as they would be in `inject(:+)` minus the overhead of symbol to proc.

Comment: Readers, recall from your high-school math that `n, n+1, n+2, .., m` constitutes an *arithmetic series* whose sum equals `(m-n+1)*(m+n)/2`. Similarly, the sum of a *geometric series*, `n, (α^1)n, (α^2)n, (α^3)n, ... , (α^m)n`. can be computed from a closed-form expression.

Comment: @CarySwoveland certainly (and I normally do that) but it's very cool to see that ruby automates it for you.

Comment: \begin{nitpick} Enumerable#sum is O((log n)^2) and inject is O(n log n) when your numbers are allowed to be unbounded. \end{nitpick}

Comment: @k_g What do you mean by unbounded numbers?

Comment: @EliSadoff: It means **really** big numbers. It means numbers which don't fit architecture word i.e. can't be computed by one instruction and one operation in CPU core. Number of size N could be encoded by log_2 N bits so addition is O(logN) operation and multiplication is O((logN)^2) but could be O((logN)^1.585) (Karasuba) or even O(logN*log(logN)*log(log(LogN)) (FFT).

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Ah. So what would have been `Bignum` in versions of ruby pre-2.4.0

Comment: @k_g and Hynek. Thanks a lot! Is the part about complexity correct now?

Comment: Yes, looks good. (When 100000000000000000) is the specific case, the log n starts mattering :-)