# Why is Range#sum defined in Enumerable module?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

In Ruby 2.4 and for Integer Ranges, [`Range(Enumerable)#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) is [optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449617/why-is-sum-so-much-faster-than-inject)  to return a result directly, without iterating over all elements.

I don't understand why the corresponding code is defined in [`enum.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L3781) for the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) module and not in [`range.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c) for [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html) class.

Why should `Enumerable` know about classes that include it (e.g. `Range`, `Hash`, ...) and check for their type instead of letting those classes overwrite `Enumerable#sum`?

Seen in `enum.c` :

```
 return int_range_sum(beg, end, excl, memo.v);
 # or
 hash_sum(obj, &memo);
```

Comment: Good question. To me it's more logical to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: ..because language designers are fallible, too? Ask the author: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/eb9c9964b08b980b05149ce91173204060917468

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, just that it is suprising. There might be a perfectly valid reason behind (e.g. performance).

Comment: @DamienRoche : Merci. I contacted the committer.

Answer (score 5):

Because [`rb_range_values`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/54bc0a446dd83c475c7ba540bccc1d9b3ad1e39a/range.c#L995) might be `true` for arbitrary class instances (not only explicit `Range`s) and we all want them to be optimized too.

Basically, it means that as soon as an instance responds to both [`begin` and `end`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/54bc0a446dd83c475c7ba540bccc1d9b3ad1e39a/range.c#L1321-L1322) (and `exclude_end?` btw,) we are to enter this optimization.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I just tried it with `class MyRange; include Enumerable;...` and `#sum` works fine, as long as `begin`, `end` and `exclude_end?` are defined. Couldn't those arbitrary classes inherit from Range when they're so Range-like?

Comment: “Couldn't those arbitrary class instances inherit from Range when they're so Range-like?”—I am definitely not a proper person to address this question :)

Comment: @EricDuminil generally speaking one would not want to inherit from a core class. That being said I agree that `Enumerable#sum` should not type check and including classes that need specific functionality should redefine `#sum` or accept the default thus resulting in `Enumerable#sum`, `Range#sum` and `Hash#sum`. This implementation of redefinition per object is perpetuated currently for classes like `Array`  and `Hash` where they implement their own versions of `#select` so I cannot see why `#sum` should be any different

Comment: "one would not want to inherit from a core class"? Why? As far as I can tell, every Class inherits from a core class in Ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I didn't notice that `rb_range_values` is defined in `range.c`. That confuses me even more!

Comment: @EricDuminil say I inherit from `Array` (e.g. `class MyArray < Array` so that I can implement a new method specifically for my purposes  in my subclass but calling any standard `Array` method gets me back an `Array` not `MyArray` so now my custom method is useless because `Array` has no knowledge of this method.

Comment: @engineersmnky this is not true. `Array` re-implements most of `Enumerable` methods, but not all of them: `class MyArray < Array; def each(&cb); yield 42; end; end; MyArray.new.all? #⇒ true ; MyArray.new.all? { |e| puts e } #⇒ 42`

Comment: @engineersmnky: Thanks for the explanation. See how Pathname is implemented. It calls `self.class.new(result)` all the time.

Comment: @mudasobwa I was not saying that `Array` redefines all `Enumerable` methods I was saying when it makes sense to have an object specific version of the method it is re implemented there in congruence with the post as to why `Range#sum` would not make this modification in place of `Enumerable#sum`

Comment: @EricDuminil yes but I would not consider `Pathname` a core class either, while it is part of the Standard Library it is not part of the core. Would you like to inherit from `Range` and wrap all the methods to ensure the return of your inheriting class? Seems contrived to me