# Is it not correct to use Ruby's arr.inject(:+) or JavaScript's arr.reduce((a,b) => { return a + b }) to sum up an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, ruby, reduce, inject

I used to think that Ruby's

```
arr.inject(:+)
```

or JavaScript's

```
arr.reduce((a, b) => { return a + b })

// a cooler way
arr.reduce( (a, b) => a + b )
```

are both the equivalent of summing the array entries up. But is it actually not correct because of this one case: what if the array is empty?

Ruby will return `nil`, and JavaScript will raise an exception. So besides using an initial value, are there also better ways to do it?

Comment: Read "[ask]". Your question is too broad. Ask about a specific language, not multiple languages.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) can accept two parameters, the first one being the initial value. If there's no element in the `Enumerable`, this initial value becomes the returned value:

```
[].inject(:+)
# nil
[].inject(0,:+)
# 0
```

As mentioned by @Ursus in the comments, Ruby 2.4 defines [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) with a default value of `0`:

```
[].sum
# 0
```

As a bonus, it's also much faster for some objects ([e.g. Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449844/6419007)).

Note that returning `nil` could sometimes be the desired result, depending on which process comes after.

Finally, kudos to JS for [raising an exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) when the array is empty and no default value has been defined. It's probably the cleanest solution.

Comment: And from ruby 2.4.0 you can use sum method, [].sum # 0

Comment: I never thought about the fact that the operation becomes the second argument if you want to add a starting value. This is kind of bad. :/ Why it is allowed to pass the accumulator in a non-block form is beyond me.

Comment: @ndn: Indeed, it feels wrong to move the argument like this. The corresponding C code isn't pretty : `switch (rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "02", &init, &op)) {...`

Comment: @EricDuminil so you mean `arr.reduce( (a, b) => a + b, 0 )` is the cleanest solution? A bit surprised that summing array entries up appears complicated

Comment: @太極者無極而生 If you want to accept empty arrays in JS, yes, I'd say that `arr.reduce( (a, b) => a + b, 0 )` is the way to go. If you want to detect empty arrays and fail as soon as possible when one is detected, you could leave `arr.reduce( (a, b) => a + b )  `.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the exception raised in case of empty array, declare an initial value.

```js
var arr = [],
    res = arr.reduce((a,b) => { return a + b }, 0);
                                              //^^ initial value
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you use a dynamically-typed language with implicit types, doesn't mean that you don't have to think about types.

In other languages, these two operations have different names (e.g. in Haskell [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) and [`foldl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl1), in Scala [`foldLeft`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B) and [`reduceLeft`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html#reduceLeft[B>:A](op:(B,A)=>B):B)), whereas in Ruby, they are overloaded, but the matter still remains that they are two distinct operations:

1. the *general* `fold` operation

   - operates on a collection of `A`s
   - has a zero element of type `B`
   - and a combining function which takes a `B` and an `A` and returns a `B`

   which means

   - it can return an object of a type other than the element type (it returns a `B`, not an `A`)
   - it can operate on an empty collection
2. the *constrained* `reduce` operation

   - operates on a collection of `A`s
   - has *no* zero element, it uses an element of the collection instead, which has type `A`
   - and a combining function which takes an `A` and an `A` and returns an `A`

   which means

   - it can only return an object of the same type as the element type (it returns an `A`)
   - it can only operate on a non-empty collection

That's also where the Haskell names come from, it is called `foldl1` because it requires at least 1 element, and takes element number 1 as the initial element.

Note that the general `fold` operation is *strictly more powerful* than the constrained `reduce` operation. In fact, the general `fold` operation is a [*universal iterator operation*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality), it can do *anything* that a `foreach` loop can do: `map`, `groupBy`, `sort`, `uniq`, `reverse`, … you name it. *Every* collection operation can be implemented as a fold.

Example:

```ruby
module Enumerable
  def my_reverse
    inject([]) {|acc, el| [el] + acc }
  end

  # this is not exactly equivalent because it's not lazy
  def my_any?
    inject(false) {|acc, el| acc || yield el }
  end
end
```

`reduce` can *not* do everything. For example, you cannot implement `reverse` using `reduce` because `reduce` returns an `A`, but `reverse` returns a `Collection<A>`; likewise, you cannot implement `any?` because it returns a `Boolean`. You can only use `reduce` if these two properties hold:

1. you want to produce a value of the same type as the element type
2. there is at least one element

In your case, #1 is true, but #2 isn't, which is why you cannot use `reduce`, you must use `fold`. I.e. in Ruby, you need to use

```ruby
ary.inject(0, :+)
```

and in ECMAScript

```ecmascript
arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0)
```

As mentioned elsewhere, Ruby *does* have [`Enumerable#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum); however, that only works for this specific case of summing the elements, but for example not for the practically identical problem of multiplying them.

Comment: Extremely interesting, as always. If I understand your `fold` description correctly, it's covered by Ruby's `each_with_object`, right?

Comment: `fold` is `inject` with initial argument. `reduce` is `inject` without initial argument. `each_with_object` is different, it doesn't use the return value of the combiner function as the accumulator value for the next iteration. It only use one single accumulator value for the entire traversal. As such, it is inherently side-effecting and impure. It is more like `fold`, however, in that there *is* an initial value of a potentially different type.